# Multivariable Optimization Problem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I'm new to optimization in multivariable calculus, so the following problem has me quite clueless:
The energy, E, necessary to compress a gas of fixed initial pressure $ P_{0} $ to a final pressure $ P_{f} $, going through an intermediary pressure $ p $, is
$$ E = (\frac{p}{P_{0}})^2 + (\frac{P_{f}}{p})^2-1 $$

How should we pick a p value that minimizes this energy? Now, suppose that the compression occurs in two stages with two intermediary pressures, p1 and p2. How should we pick p1 and p2 that minimize the necessary energy E, which is given by
$$ E = (\frac{p_{1}}{P_{0}})^2+(\frac{p_{2}}{p_{1}})^2+(\frac{P_{f}}{p_{2}})^2 -2\ ? $$
I managed to solve the first equation, but my doubts arise from the second. For instance, I was only able to get to $p_{1}=\sqrt{P_{0}p_{2}} $. How would you go about getting to the optimal result here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the minimum of multivariable function is quite similar to finding the minimum of singlevariable function. As you know at the extrema the value of a derivative has to be zero. The extrema of multivariable function have the same condition - the partial derivates (there is one for every variable) have to be zero.

This creates a system of equations and the solution is critical point. Just like for singlevariable function this criterion is not sufficient to claim the critical point is an extreme though.

For singlevariable function one checks the second derivative in order to determine whether and what kind of extreme is at a point with zero derivative. Positive second derivative means there is maximum, negative corresponds with minimum.

For multivariable function one has to construct the Hessian matrix $H$ and analyze it in order to know the character.

If all eigenvalues are positive, the function is convex at the point, critical point is a maximum.
If all are negative, the function is concave at that point, critical point is a minimum.
If eigenvalues differ in sign there is neither maximum nor minimum at the point.

Your example would be solved as follows:

Partial derivatives equal 0 in critical point:

$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial p_1} = \frac{2p_1}{P_0^2}-\frac{2p_2^2}{p_1^3} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial p_2} = \frac{2p_2}{p_1^2}-\frac{2P_f^2}{p_2^3} = 0$$

Solution to this system is
$$ p_1^3 = P_fP_0^2$$
$$p_2^4 = p_1^2P_f^2 $$

We should now analyze the Hessian matrix in order to characterize this critical point but I'll stop here because matrix formating is going wild for me and it is fairly obvious that this is our wanted minimum.